# Insert or update many documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to insert or update/replace multiple documents in MongoDB with a single query?

Assume the following collection:

```
[
    {_id: 1, text: "something"},
    {_id: 4, text: "baz"}
]
```

Now I would like to add multiple documents of which some might already be in the collection. If the documents are already in the collection, I would like to update/replace them. For example, I would like to insert the following documents:

```
[
    {_id:1, text: "something else"},
    {_id:2, text: "foo"},
    {_id:3, text: "bar"}
]
```

The query should insert the documents with `_id` 2 and 3. It should also update/replace the document with `_id` 1. After the process, the collection should look as follows:

```
[
    {_id:1, text: "something else"},
    {_id:2, text: "foo"},
    {_id:3, text: "bar"},
    {_id:4, text: "baz"}
]
```

One approach might be to use [`insertMany`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/):

```
db.collection.insertMany(
   [ {...}, {...}, {...} ],
   {
      ordered: false,
   }
)
```

If duplicates occur, that query will emit a `writeErrors` containing an array of objects containing the indexes of the documents that failed to insert. I could go through them and update them instead.

**But that process is cumbersome. Is there a way to insert or update/replace many documents in *one* query?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As said [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#insert-for-bulk-find-update), to do what you need you can put something like this in

script.js

(*** warning: untested code**)

```
use YOUR_DB
var bulk = db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { _id : 1 } ).upsert().update( { $set: { "text": "something else" } } );
bulk.find( { _id : 4 } ).upsert().update( { $set: { "text": "baz" } } );
bulk.find( { _id : 99 } ).upsert().update( { $set: { "text": "mrga" } } );
bulk.execute();
```

and run it with

mongo < script.js

I had to do it this way as anything I tried for updating/inserting more than 1000 documents didn't work because of the limit.

> Write commands can accept no more than 1000 operations. The Bulk() operations in the mongo shell and comparable methods in the drivers do not have this limit.

[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Write-Command-Operation-Limit-Size)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use bulkWrite api to update or insert multiple documents in a single query, here is an example

```
var ops = []

items.forEach(item => {
    ops.push(
        {
            updateOne: {
                filter: { _id: unique_id },
                update: {
                    $set: { fields_to_update_if_exists },
                    $setOnInsert: { fileds_to_insert_if_does_not_exist }
                },
                upsert: true
            }
        }
    )
})

db.collections('collection_name').bulkWrite(ops, { ordered: false });
```

Answer (score 4):

Considering data item as follows:

```
interface Item {
    id: string;         // unique key across collection
    someValue: string;
}
```

If you have items under the limit 1000, you can make bulk write operation like this:

```
public async insertOrUpdateBulk(items: Item[]) {
        try {
            const bulkOperation = this._itemCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
            for (let itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items.length; itemIndex++) {
                const item = items[itemIndex];
                bulkOperation.find({ id: item.id }).upsert().update(item);
            }
            await bulkOperation.execute();
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If you have items that exceed the limit 1000, you can make simultaneous promises:

```
public async insertOrUpdate(items: Item[]) {
        try {
            const promises: Array<Promise<UpdateWriteOpResult>> = [];
            for (let itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < items.length; itemIndex++) {
                const item = items[itemIndex];
                const updatePromise = this.itemCollection.updateOne({ id: item.id }, item, { upsert: true });
                promises.push(updatePromise);
            }
            await Promise.all(promises);
            console.log('done...');
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm getting `multi update only works with $ operators'`

Comment: I am getting 'multi update only works with $ operator' as well