# MongoDB Insert Many, Update Many

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB in node.js. I'm trying to update or insert many documents based on different conditions; however, MongoDB update (with upsert) only works with a single document or many documents with the same condition. Currently, I have an array containing the objects that I want to insert (Or update if the unique index exists) and I'm looping through the array and calling the updateOnce; however, I believe this method is not very efficient for a large number of objects that I'm going to have. 
What is a better way to achieve this?

```js
var mongoUtil = require( './database.js' );
var db = mongoUtil.getDb();
//array of objects to insert:
//NOTE: First + Last name is a unique index
var users = [
  {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", points:300},
  {firstName:"Mickey", lastName:"Mouse", points:200}
];

var collection = db.collection( 'points' );

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  //If firstName and lastName already exists, update points. Otherwise insert new object
  collection.updateOne(
    {firstName: users[i].firstName, lastName: users[i].lastName},
    {$set: {points: users[i].points}},
    {upsert: true},
    function(err,docs) {
      if(err)
      console.log(err);
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Probably this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244739/insert-or-update-many-documents-in-mongodb. Please check out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue using .bulkWrite():

```js
var mongoUtil = require( './database.js' );
var db = mongoUtil.getDb();
var collection = db.collection( 'points' );

var users = [
  {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", points:300},
  {firstName:"Mickey", lastName:"Mouse", points:200}
];

let userUpdate = users.map(user => ({
    updateOne: {
      filter: {firstName: user.firstName, lastName: user.lastName},
      update: {$set: user},
      upsert: true
    }
  }));
  collection.bulkWrite(userUpdate).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);

  });
```