# Aggregate indexes of document with same name

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a vectorstore in mongodb. The schema is as given below
Inside my `vectorstore_db` database, I have a `value_embeddings` collection and within that are documents which have indexes of various documents that have array types.

I'm inserting them by reading from a json file and writing using `insertmany` as follows:

```
client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client["vectorstore_db"]

val_embeddings_table = db["value_embeddings"]

with open("value_embeddings.json") as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)
val_embeddings_table.insert_many(file_data)

client.close()
```

What I'd like to do here is, merge two documents which have the same `column_name` (like below "gender"). The new document would have only the union of unique elements from both documents.

Should I change the way I'm writing to the db (check if it exists. If exists, then update) or do this aggregation while reading?

I'm just a beginner in handling dbs and hence this screenshot instead of elaborate schema diagrams. Any help on this would be great.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could try to work with bulkWrite and updateOne with upsert=true to achieve the insert/update (cf : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244739/insert-or-update-many-documents-in-mongodb).
An easier solution but not beautiful is to run an aggreagation with `$group` stage by `column_name` with an `$push` accumulator to add all values, followed by a `$out` stage that outputs the results in a new collection.